# Questions about object superclasses and casting

Tags: java, oop

I'm preparing for a java exam. I came across the following question

```
String s = new String ("hello");
Object o = (object) s;
```

Since `o` and `s` are both references that point to the same object, is there any difference in accessing the object through the reference `s` over the reference `o`?

Would I be right in saying that all objects (like the one being reference by s) are subclasses of `Object` in Java and as such using the reference `s` you will be able to call the methods known by the superclass `Object` like `clone()` and the methods known by `String` like `length()`. Whereas, the superclass object reference `o` will only be able to call it's own methods and not those of the subclass?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this statement is correct.

Comment: You are exactly correct.

Comment: Two small notes: you don't need to explicitly cast s to `Object` (an upcast can always be implicit), and you don't need to create `new String("hello")` -- you can just write `String s = "hello"`, and `s` will still be a reference to a `String` object, same as in your code -- albeit one that lives in a different place (in permgen instead of on the GC "heap").

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that by using o you will not be able to call string specific methods unless you cast it back to String.

However, any method that you call on o that is defined on the String class will call the later version of the method. For example, o.toString() will return "hello", and not the descriptor that the Object.toString() normally returns. This is called polymorphism.